# Pivoting 1,620 columns to rows in 360gb text file in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, amazon-redshift, etl, amazon-athena

I have a pipe delimited text file that is 360GB, compressed (gzip). 
It has over 1,620 columns. I can't show the exact field names, but here's basically what it is:

```
primary_key|property1_name|property1_value|property800_name|property800_value
12345|is_male|1|is_college_educated|1
```

Seriously, there are over 800 of these property name/value fields.
There are roughly 280 million rows. 
The file is in an S3 bucket.
I need to get the data into Redshift, but the column limit in Redshift is 1,600.

The users want me to pivot the data. For example:

```
primary_key|key|value
12345|is_male|1
12345|is_college_educated|1
```

What is a good way to pivot the file in the aws environment? The data is in a single file, but I'm planning on splitting the data into many different files to allow for parallel processing.

I've considered using Athena. I couldn't find anything that states the maximum number of columns allowed by Athena. But, I found a page about Presto (on which Athena is based) that says “there is no exact hard limit, but we've seen stuff break with more than few thousand.” (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/7tv8l6MsbzI).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, pivot your data, then load to Redshift.

In more detail, the steps are:

1. Run a spark job (using EMR or possibly AWS Glue) which reads in your
   source S3 data and writes out (to a different s3 folder) a pivoted
   version. by this i mean if you have 800 value pairs, then you would
   write out 800 rows. At the same time, you can split the file into multiple parts to enable parallel load.
2. "COPY" this pivoted data into Redshift

Answer (score 1):

What I learnt from most of the time from AWS is, if you are reaching a limit, you are doing it in a wrong way or not in a scalable way. Most of the time architects designed with scalability, performance in mind.

We had similar problems, having 2000 columns. Here is how we solved it.

1. Split the file across 20 different tables, 100+1 (primary key) column each.
2. Do a select across all those tables in a single query to return all the data you want.
3. If you say you want to see all the 1600 columns in a select, then the business user is looking at wrong columns for their analysis or even for machine learning.

To load 10TB+ of data we had split the data into multiple files and load them in parallel, that way loading was faster.

Between Athena and Redshift, performance is the only difference. Rest of them are same. Redshift performs better than Athena. Initial Load time and Scan Time is higher than Redshift.

Hope it helps.